# error in npm start vs code , react project

Tags: node.js

H!
i tryin to run my React Project using npm start command in terminal :

```
npm v7.4.3
node v15.7.0
```

error in terminal

```
./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/index.scss)
```

Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1

and face this error in localhost:8888

> Failed to compile
> ./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/index.scss)
> Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)
> For more information on which environments are supported please see:
> https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1

i trying tso solve problem with this commands

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

and other way was reinstall node-sass
im trying to delete node_modules and run npm install

but seem doesnt work for me.
any answers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade node.js to a stable version (LTS) like  [14.15.4](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Install the compatible node-sass version via `npm install node-sass@5.0.0`; you can find the list [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) or use the [GitHub releases page](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases), or even install `gulp-sass with` npm i gulp-sass`.